# Disable notification center for an iPhone app in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, notifications, center, local

I would like my app to show notifications to the user at the top of the screen while the phone is in use, and I would also like the notifications to show on the lock screen.

I don't however want the notifications to show in notification center - The app notifies without requiring the user to launch the app, and thus there is no way for me to clear the unnecessary / annoying build up of notifications that will appear in the notification center.

Users can manually control this from Notifications in Settings by setting "Notification Center" for that app to "Off" - Is there a way I can specify this at app install time? (I am aware this was not possible in iOS 5).

Thanks!